# Yum: I don't see any files installed

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I tend to ask the most stupid questions here, but here goes again:

I installed postgresql92, as proven here:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ yum info postgresql92.x86_64
Loaded plugins: presto, security
Installed Packages
Name        : postgresql92
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.1
Release     : 20.el6.centos.alt
Size        : 0.0
Repo        : installed
From repo   : scl
Summary     : Package that installs postgresql92
License     : GPLv2+
Description : This is the main package for postgresql92 Software Collection, which installs
            : necessary packages to use PostgreSQL 9.2 server. Software Collections allow
            : to install more versions of the same package by using alternative
            : directory structure.
            : Install this package if you want to use PostgreSQL 9.2 server on your system.
```

However, when I look for it, I see nothing:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ rpm -ql postgresql92
(contains no files)
```

If I do something else like `rpm -ql gcc`, I start seeing files.

Is there a rpm hash that needs to be updated?

Comment: Have you tried looking at postgresql92 dependencies? From the description, I understand it's a meta package that doesn't install any files itself, only pulls required packages.

Answer (score 1):

The `postgresql92` package is a "metapackage", meaning it requires other packages, but provides no files.

It's part of [CentOS SCL](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) (The Software Collections Repository. Installing the file configures CentOS and requires other packages to be installed, including:

- postgresql92-postgresql-server
- postgresql92-postgresql
- postgresql92-postgresql-libs
- postgresql92-runtime

If you are looking for the PostgreSQL 9.2 files on your system, try `rpm -ql postgresql92-postgresql-server`.